# Website Startup slider not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I am working on a clients website [Website](http://vaionyva.com/)

The first slider was working but don't know why the its not functioning.
the slider with YOUR LIFE wordings.

Can any body please check the website and let me know where is the issue
here is the html code

```
<div id="splash-show">
<div class="show-slide">
    <img src="http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/yourlife.png">
<!--/show-slide--></div>
<div class="show-slide">
    <img src="http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/yourlove.png">
<!--/show-slide--></div>
<div class="show-slide">
    <img src="http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/thismoment.png">
<!--/show-slide--></div>
<div class="show-slide">
    <img src="http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/logo.png">
<!--/show-slide--></div>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working, what is it supposed to look like? "the slider with YOUR LIFE wordings." is not a sentence and doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: please check the code above.. i have just added. its basically a slider which is not working. after this slider the whole site loads. Don't know who developed it. I am just fixing some errors like this one

Comment: Nothing looks broken to me?

Comment: But there is some thing that's why the slider is not working. I found this error with fire bug.

[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Dont know what this means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Supersized for Wordpress.

When I load your website the first image that I see is the "Your Life" Slide, but it disappears after the webpage/whole slideshow loads so I assume the problem is that the said image it does not become part of the slideshow itself.

If I understood your question correctly you can easily add your images here in the javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $.supersized({
                                    slideshow               : 1,
                    autoplay        : 1,
                                                    start_slide             : 1,
                                                    random          : 1,
                    slide_interval          : 5000,
                    transition              : 1,
                    transition_speed    : 1000,
                    new_window      : 1,
                    pause_hover             : 1,
                                        stop_loop               : 1,
                    keyboard_nav            : 1,
                    performance     : 1,

                                                    image_protect       : 1,
                    image_path      : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-supersized/img/',
                    min_width       : 1200,
                    min_height      : 0,
                    vertical_center         : 1,
                    horizontal_center       : 1,
                                        fit_always          : 0,
                    fit_portrait            : 0,
                    fit_landscape       : 0,
                                    thumbnail_navigation    : 0,
                                        thumb_links             : 1,
                    slide_counter           : 0,
                    slide_captions          : 0,  
                                                    slides                  :  [
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/yourlife.png', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/yourlove.png', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/thismoment.png', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/themes/perfekto/images/splash/logo.png', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_0125.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9668.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9669.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9950.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9958.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_0122.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9552.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9610.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9794.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9937.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'http://vaionyva.com/wp-content/sliders/IMG_9995.JPG', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''}],
                                        slide_links             : 'blank',
                                        progress_bar        : 0,                        
                    mouse_scrub     : 1                                             
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: please vote my answer up by checking the check mark if this helped you :)